# How to analyze category responses

Tags: spss, categorical-data

In a survey questionnaire I asked participants to give a priority ranking to the question "What factor motivates a lot for wringing out loyalty, and productivity?", with the following choices: "Good Salary, Promotions, Respect & Recognition, Reward & Appreciation, Organization's Reputation, Medical & Family care, Good Leadership, Challenging work & Targets, National & International Trainings opportunities, Job Security etc etc (total 15 variables)"

Respondents gave different priority number to different variables, for example someone gave 1 to Money, 2 to Medical Care, similarly someone gave 1 to Medical Care and 2 to Reward, 3 to Job Security... and so on. Every respondent gave different reasons & priority numbers. Now how can I analyse such data in SPSS because my coding of 1 priority is 5 or 6 of respondent's priority.

**Edit**: I wanna to find out that How much or What percent of respondents gave to PRIORITY 1, then 2, 3 because there were 261 respondents. What i want to say is for example i question that "What factors motivates you to Resign from my factory and someone reply MONEY as priority 1 and Job security as Priority 3, similarly someone reply Money as priority 5 and Respect is priority 1... so on". How i can analyse them and get result of that How much gave priority 1 to ?, 2 to ? and so on, their percentage? More clearly for example i want to know that in my factory 80% employee will resign because of ? 75% will resign because of ? and so on. I need to know how SPSS can perform this (Please note that i can not give priority to any variable because it is not me but my employees are responsible to give me their "preference list" priority wise which indicates serial 15 reasons to resign on priority / importance basis?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  

First, it would have been good to think about how to analyze the data *before* you started collecting it. Second, what are you trying to find out?

Comment: Could you please share a little bit about what your intentions were when you got started and how many individuals took the survey?  Did they really have to rate the options from one to 15?

Comment: Similar to this issue?: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27655/how-to-analyse-a-ranking-and-rating-scale-together/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to provide your respondents with ranking scale to measure their priority to the variables in your questionnaire. You can do that with likert scales or construct your ranking order so that the respondents can rank based on the ranking orders that meet their own priorities such as: Agree, strongly agree, undecided, Disagree, Strongly disagree. Make sure that your ranking scales measure all the variables and their spellings in each variable are uniform. Then after coding the responses, while analyzing the data in SPSS, go to tables >custom tables; a dialogue box will appear with all the variables; select the ones you wish to analyze to the left conner titled rows. After that, click the icon 'summary statistics' and select the type of statistics you want such as Row N %, click apply to selection. In the down part of the dialogue box, by default, position appears in columns, click and change it to rows. In the right side, by default, category position appears 'default', click to change to 'rows and columns'. Tick the 'hide' icon and click OK. The result should appear as you want. Note: the category position will not highlight if your response lebels are not uniform for all variables highlighted. I hope this helps you.

Comment: You might try to edit you answer (you can do so by clicking the "edit" link in lower left) to improve basic grammar (e.g. capitalizing the first word of each sentence, etc.).