# Likert Scale vs Conjoint Analysis. Which to use?

Tags: likert, conjoint-analysis

I am planning to conduct a questionnaire to obtain information of a tenant's perspective on management in a building. I would need to ask the tenants to fill up the questionnaire about how important they think each element in a management is. The sample size will be $n = 300$.

I am not sure if a Likert scale would work better or a conjoint analysis in this situation.

The outcome of the questionnaire must allow me to rank the elements in the building management according to the importance perceived by the tenants. I would have roughly 20 items to rank.

For example, items to rank are: Cleanliness, Security, Maintenance, Repair.
When I get back the data, I would have to be able to rank them according to importance, e.g.:

1. Cleanliness,
2. Repair,
3. Maintenance,
4. Security

So I would like to know how I should structure my questionnaire to achieve this. And could you suggest me any test that allows me to analyse the data to rank them?

Comment: Conjoint analysis is not in contradiction with likert rating scales. The Q is unclear therefore.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest going with a Likert-scale survey rather than conjoint, **or** maybe even better: have respondents allocate 100 points across the attributes.  In my experience, conjoint makes most sense when you want to include price as an attribute with the hopes of teasing out willingness to pay. I can imagine it seeming odd to tenants if one presented them with different options and price points, asking them which they would choose, but allocating a finite number of points would still achieve your goal of understanding relative importance of each factor.

Comment: The answer makes no sense to me.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116324/analysing-data-on-importance-ratings